# Python application in old and new Windows

Tags: python, window

I've been doing Python applications lately, but I've only tested it on Windows 10 (and sometimes on Windows 7).

Now, I need to create an app to be available on Windows XP and 98 also. From my research, I've seen Python drooped Win9x/NT support at version 2.5.4.

There are alternative builds: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/162317-python-27-for-windows-95/ but, I want to know from your experience, what is the best practice to create this application and to make it as plug and play?

Answer (score 1):

Everything under python 2.7 is just death, try to make it as cross-platform friendly so you can work it out.
One tip I know when working with that kind of stuff is not to use `os.system()` functions and such. It's better to find a library that interacts with it under the hood.